# Weight painting not moving model as expected

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, rigging, weight-painting

I am trying to weight paint my model but no matter what weight I paint or assign to the verts, I can't get the skin stretching effect I want. They all act as if they have full weight and only the verts next to the ones I painted stretch.

[image: Pic 1]
Add verts to head and then rotate to test. Only the faces next to the verts selected stretches.

[image: Pic 2]
I go into edit mode and assign the line of vert's bellow at a very low weight but when I go to rotate, they move as if assigned at full weight.

Comment: "*They all act as if they have full weight*" Not at all a weight painting expert, but looking at your image I see all vertex painted red, so they *are* all at full weight. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect red(full weight) vert's to be moved completely with the bone and those with low weight to move slightly with the bone. It might be hard to see by color but if you look at the pictures, you can see there was an added row of blocks that move with the rotation of the bone that before stretched. The lower part of those blocks are discolored from the base blue because I used a low weight to add them yet they act as if I used full weight. No matter what weight I paint or add vert's to the bone, it acts as if it's at full weight when I go to rotate.

Comment: If they did have full weight, the face would remain the same shape when you rotate it. Also when you have multiple bones, make sure the the vertices have no additional weighting to another bone that you also might rotate when testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A weight of 1 (red) means, that your mesh will react 100% to the bone movement.
A weight of 0 (blue) means, that your mesh will not react at all.

So, if you want a more natural behavior, select the lower vertices of the head and assign a weight of 0.5 (green). These vertices will only be partially affected. You can go further and have several transition loops:
Assign it like this to the top bone.

[image: Weight Transition]

And assign reverse weights to the bottom bone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the reason It acts as if it's added at 100 weight is because I only have one bone weighted. I need overlap the mesh of the next bone so the vert's stretch correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try not to paint everything red and maybe add more vertex to the joint